# why response.d returns null while response has a valid set of results - in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use Web Api in my application. Everything seems to be working accept reading the json data. Below is my jQuery code that calls the web api method, and the values of the variables. As you may see, `response.d` returns an undefined value whereas `response` actually has a set of values.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Here is the web api method:

```
        public IEnumerable<DiscussionWall> GetDiscussionWallsByCourse(int courseid)
    {
        gEchoLuDBContext db = new gEchoLuDBContext();
        var discussionwalls = db.DiscussionWalls.Where(dw => dw.CourseId == courseid);

        if (discussionwalls == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        else
            return discussionwalls;
    }
```

Why I cannot simply use response.d in this case? Response is in this format `{ $id="1", $values=[3] }`? How can I read $values array?

Comment: what is d in  this case ? your response contains a list of objects . m i right ? try indexing on it. response[0]

Comment: @RohitArora,  ASP.NET and WCF JSON service endpoints actually wrap their JSON in an object with the “d” property to circumvent a subtle potential security flaw when using JSON (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/). Also, when I use `var a = response[0]`, a is undefined.

Comment: WebApi doesn't use `.d` in the response.

Comment: Also, `discussionwalls` will never be null, but it could be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line solved the problem.

```
var discussionwalls = response['$values'];
```

However, I wonder if  this creates a security issue, and I wonder why response.d did not work in this scenario. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: From the article you linked, it looks like it's not a problem for modern browsers. "The good news is that it seems to me that most modern browsers are not affected by this. I have a URL you can click on to demonstrate the exploit, but you have to use FireFox 2.0 or earlier to get the exploit to work. It didn’t work with IE 6, 7, 8, FireFox 3 nor Google Chrome."

Comment: @jrummell I see. However, I could not find any other examples that uses `response['$values'];`, do you have any web api examples that retrieve the values (array type) from response without using `.d`?

Comment: I'm not sure why want to use `response[$values]` when you could just access the array normally. I haven't seen any examples with .d, but a great place to start is [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

Comment: @jrummell actually, I checked that resource. However, in my case, interestingly, using `response` did not work. It worked only when I use `response['$values'];`. When I debug it, and hover response, this is what I see: `object { $id="1", $values=[3] }`

Comment: What if you return `discussionwalls.ToArray()`? You're technically serializing `DbQuery<T>` right now.